# Mysterious null value added to the beginning of my array

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am creating an online voting system using Django. I am trying to pass the id of the candidate in the database from client side back to server side in the order they appear to the user.

I am using Django's templating language to add the data to `<meta>` tags as below:

```
{% for candidate in candidates %}
    <meta id="cand" data-id="{{candidate.id}}" data-order="{{forloop.counter}}">
{% endfor %}
```

I understand this is bad practice but I didn't know how else to do this.

The problem arises when adding the values to the array. The part of the script that tackles this is here:

```
var button = $("#send");

$(button).click(function() {

    var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
    var cands = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < metatags.length; i++) {
        cands.push(metatags[i].dataset.id);
        // console.log(cands);
    };
    cands = JSON.stringify(cands);
    console.log(cands);
```

When I do this the console is showing an array with all the candidate IDs, but a null value at the beginning. My best guess as to why is that a `<meta>` is created some other way in the rendering of the page (possibly by the bootstrap I have used?) which is being caught by `document.getElementsByTagName('meta')`.

What is the best way to avoid the null value? Should I remove the null from the array or should I collect the tags in a different way? And since I'm a complete novice, how do I implement either of these solutions?

Comment: I think there's another `meta` tag in your document. Maybe in the `head` of HTML and it doesn't have a `data-id` attribute. Hence, null is being appended to the array.

Comment: @xyres That's what I thought as well as indicated above. How do I remove it?

Comment: The answer posted by Randy Casburn below should help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more selective with your selector :-) In order to select only our tags and not any injected by someone else.

If it is unlikely any other meta tag will use `data-id` you could select based upon that, or `data-order` if that provides higher probability of being unique to your project. As a last resort you could come up with a unique data attribute. But I'll use `data-id` for an example:

**Replace**

```
var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');
```

**With**

```
var metatags = document.querySelectorAll('meta[data-id]');
```

This gives you an additional benefit of being able to use `.forEach()` on the collection to simplify your code thus:

```
    var cands = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('meta[data-id]')
        .forEach(m=>{cands.push(m.dataset.id); console.log(cands);});
    cands = JSON.stringify(cands);
    console.log(cands);
```

Note the small change. Rather than storing the output, it is used directly to iterate over.